# Sammy.js not understanding my json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sammy.js

I´m using sammy.js with a ASP.NET MVC Backend. I have a route that loks like this:

```
        this.get("#/member/inbox", function (context) {
          this.load('CurrentUser/Messages')
            .then(function (items) {
                $.each(items, function (i, item) {
                    context.log(item.Subject, '-', item.Text);
                });
            });
```

But item.Subject and item.Text is undefined. My json looks like this:

```
[{"Text":"Lorem ipsum","Created":"\/Date(1343375945089)\/","Subject":"test"},{"Text":"testext","Created":"\/Date(1343375945089)\/","Subject":"test2"}]
```

If I exchange this-load with a call to $.get it works but I want to do this "the sammy way"
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue.  I've found that sammy will load a local file saved as .json correctly. But anything that is called from http will not work even with ("Content-type", "application/json")

You can test your own set-up by copy/pasting your own api json feed into a file.
Then see if sammy is able to load it correctly.

```
this.get('#/contact', function(context) {
     $('#header').html('This is the Contact Page')
       this.load('Backboneapp_data.json')
      .then(function(items) {
            $.each(items, function(i, item) {
              context.log(item);
            });
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that "items" is an array?  A quick check is to `console.log(items)` and see what you get.  Chances are the array is not a top-level thing, but rather there is a wrapper object holding the array so that your JSON actually looks more like this by the time it makes it up to the browser (take note of object and the "d" property):

```
{"d": [{"Text":"Lorem ipsum","Created":"\/Date(1343375945089)\/","Subject":"test"},{"Text":"testext","Created":"\/Date(1343375945089)\/","Subject":"test2"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script that generates JSON should set the HTTP `Content-type` to `application/json` or `text/json`

For ASP.NET this would be:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/json";
```

or

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I changed line 1535 in sammy.js 
from:

```
dataType: is_json ? 'json' : 'text'
```

to:

```
dataType: is_json ? 'json' : null
```

And now sammy understands that the content is json, not sure why at this moment.

Comment: Modify your question instead of answering your own question with a hack

Answer (score 0):

There's definitely something to improve in the Sammy code in those cases. What I do when I have this situation is use

```
var jsonItems = $.parseJSON(items);
```

This will generate a proper JSON object from the response.